# Does <cstring> not include the strcat_s() function?

Tags: c++, c-strings, strcat

My code is this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
const int LENGTH1 = 25;

char array_str1[LENGTH1] = "Hey guys! "; 
char array_str2[] = "What's up?"; 

string std_str1 = "Hello everyone! ";
string std_str2 = "How's tricks?";

int main(){ 
    strcat_s(array_str1, LENGTH1, array_str2);
    std_str1 += std_str2;
    cout << std_str1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I get the error:

> use of undeclared identifier 'strcat_s'

If I comment out the `strcat_s` line, the rest of the code runs fine.

I'm working from a tutorial, and even if I copy-paste the working code from the tutorial, I get the same error. I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.60.0 on MacOS 10.14.16.

Comment: [`strcat_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) is a C function, it is not provided by C++. `<cstring>` is a C++ header.

Comment: And why does C++ not provide such a useful-sounding function? Because it's not all that useful. Use `std::string`.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is not a compiler.  Which compiler are you using with it? Some compilers provide `strcat_s`, some don't

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that "working code" from the tutorial is from an author utilizing the Visual C++ toolchain, which *does* include `strcat_s` (and all the other `insertnamehere_s` functions) as part of their implementation, including their C++ runtime. But it is *not* standard C++. MS even goes as far as providing a template version deducing the non-type template length parameter in the event you're using declared arrays (like you are); also utterly not part of the standard C++ library.

Comment: More specifically, `strcat_s` was introduced to the C language in C11.  C++ does not promise to add functions that were added to another language.

Comment: `#include <string>` -- A C++ looking at your code will quickly point out that you are including `<string>`.  So why are you using `strcat_s` and not `std::string`?

Comment: @DrewDormann -- I just realized that.  Amended my comment.

Comment: *If I comment out the strcat_s line, the rest of the code runs fine.* -- And if you leave it commented out and instead used `std::string` throughout your code, you would be better off.

Answer (score 2):

> Is `<cstring>` not including the strcat function?

`<cstring>` does declare `std::strcat`.

Sidenote: Don't use `std::strcat`; you won't need it. Use `std::string`.

> ```
> strcat_s(array_str1, LENGTH1, array_str2);
> ```

`strcat_s` is not `std::strcat`. Even though there is `std::strcat` in the C++ standard library, there is no `strcat_s`.

Sidenote: There is `strcat_s` in the C standard library (since C11). C is a different language. Even in C, `strcat_s` is not guaranteed to be supported, and not all language implementations provide it.

Comment: All of which only goes to demonstrate, lest we forget, that C++ is no longer a 'superset' of C.

Comment: ... So if you're going to code in C++, you should forget everything you know about C and [do it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).